# Unity3D points on sprites only on Play Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a problem and I can't solve it at all. I have several simple sprites (SpriteRenderer). In Play Mode some points appear on some of them, which are not in Editor Mode.
[image: This is in Edior Mode]

Above is the prite in Editor Mode. It has no point on it, it's ok.
[image: Play Mode]
And watch what's happening in Play Mode.
I opened the sprite in Paint.Net, saved it as PNG, then reopened it and saved it again in JPG, and it solved the problem. Ok, but I want to know why Unity does this, and why it happens, that I have a lot of sprites that require this operation (Paint.Net -> Save PNG-> Save JPG and rewrite)

Sorry for the English and thanks in advance. Any help will be helpful.